# Is there a way to fix Java Springboot error related to module cycles?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have developed a springboot micro service where two modules communicate with each other. However, whenever i try to run a module, i get this error:

```
Annotation processing is not supported for module cycles. Please ensure that all modules from cycle [rooms,students] are excluded from annotation processing
```

How will I fix it?

Comment: I believe the presence of a cyclic dependency error is intentional and you should not seek to resolve it by simply ignoring it. It is worth noting that one of the key benefits of using microservices architecture is to minimize dependencies between services. Therefore, it might be useful to consider extracting the common logic into a separate service as a potential solution to reduce the coupling between the services

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you need to exclude one or both of the modules from annotation processing.
You can try adding this to your build.gradle file.

```
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        exclude module: 'rooms'
        exclude module: 'students'
    }
}
```

Note: Cyclic dependencies are not recommended. You should consider resolving them.

Maven pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>rooms/**</exclude>
          <exclude>students/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I am using maven instead of gradle. How will i go by it?

Comment: I updated the content.
I'm not very familiar with Maven, but I can give you some examples to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. But it still doesn't work